# Determine boolean equation from binary array input

Tags: arrays, neural-network, binary, boolean, artificial-intelligence

I have an array of 4096 16 bit integers that have been determined by some unknown formula. Can anyone suggest any AI / NN that would allow the formula to be determined so that I can expand the array to 8192 points

Comment: Without some a-priori *model* or *assumptions*, copying the 4096 integers is as good as putting 4096 zeros in theory. See ["regularization"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)).

Comment: Do you have any specifications on the formula? Is it a function of known form but just missing constants?

Comment: Its a radix 8 digit reversing algorithm. I can manually figure the first 64 elements. There is a pattern for 0,2,4, and a different pattern for 1,3,5..